# frozenset at least x elements

Tags: python, frozenset

I currently have this code, it checks if all elements in the array are the same. If this is the case, return true

```
def all_equal(lst):
  """
  >>> all_equal([1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
  True
  >>> all_equal([1,2,3,1])
  False
  """
  return len(frozenset(lst)) == 1
```

But what I do want to check is if there are atleast 5 elements of the same.

So that

```
[1,1,1,1,1,2,2]
```

Will return True aswell. Since there are 5 times 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using a set, use a [*bag* or *multiset* type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). A multiset counts how many times unique values occur.

In Python that's the [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def all_equal(lst):
    bag = Counter(lst)
    if any(v >= 5 for v in bag.itervalues()):
        # an element occurred at least 5 times
        # (use bag.values() if using Python 3)
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: But this returns True even if its not true

Comment: @Sharpless512: so when is it *not* true? Please be specific.

Comment: @Sharpless512: your question implies you want to return true for two conditions: either there is only 1 unique element, *or* there are at least 5 occurrences of an element. That's what I coded up, if that is wrong, you need to clarify your question.

Comment: It should only return True if there at atleast 5 occurrences of the same element

Comment: @Sharpless512: so you want to *ignore* the "only one unique value* case? Then simply drop the first `if` test. Please do make this clear in your question, it reads now as if you want to *add* the second test to your existing function.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def all_equal(lst, count):
    return any(v >= count for v in Counter(lst).values())
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer using `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def some_equal(lst):
    return max(Counter(lst).values()) >= 5
```

`Counter` is a "set" counting occurences of its elements.
 `Counter.keys()` returns the elements, and `Counter().values()` returns numbers of their occurences. Thus this `max` ensures there is an element which occures more than 5 times.

Comment: `max()` will look through all values whereas you could stop on the first value >= 5.

Comment: @eugeney Well, asymptotically the complexity is same :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also check as you go, short circuiting as you iterate if any value is 5:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def five(it):
    d  = defaultdict(int)
    for ele in it:
        d[ele] += 1
        if d[ele] == 5:
            return True
    return False
```

You could use a Counter but to just count the *defaultdict* is as fast and sometimes actually faster.